# Mongoskin will not fetch some results from mongodb in nodejs app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I wanted to read some data from a mongodb via mongoskin. But nodejs throws me an error when i try to call localhost:3000/tasks

In my database 'todo' there are some items in the collection 'tasks'. The result in the console works fine when i start the app.

Can anyone see where i wrote something wrong?

The eroor message:

```
500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'tasks' of undefined
at exports.list (/Users/piet/Websites/privat/mongo/routes/tasks.js:7:8) at callbacks     (/Users/piet/Websites/privat/mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
at param (/Users/piet/Websites/privat/mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
at pass (/Users/piet/Websites/privat/mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
at Router._dispatch    (/Users/piet/Websites/privat/mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
at Object.router   (/Users/piet/Websites/privat/mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
at next   (/Users/piet/Websites/privat/mongo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:    15)
at Object.methodOverride [as handle]  (/Users/piet/Websites/privat/mongo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/me    thodOverride.js:48:5)
at next (/Users/piet/Websites/privat/mongo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:    15)
at Object.urlencoded [as handle]   (/Users/piet/Websites/privat/mongo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/ur    lencoded.js:49:37)
```

My app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var tasks = require('./routes/tasks');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var mongo = require("mongoskin");
var db = mongo.db('localhost:27017/todo?auto_reconnect=true', { 
safe:true })
.collection('tasks')
.find()
.toArray(function(error, items){
    console.log(items);
})

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
   app.use(express.errorHandler());
}
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/tasks', tasks.list);
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

The route file under /routes/tasks.js

```
exports.list = function(req, res, next){
req.db.tasks.find({
    completed: false
}).toArray(function(error, tasks){
    res.render('tasks', {
        title: "ToDo list",
        name: tasks = tasks || []
    })
})
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use 28017 as port id. You can check what you are getting in "req.db". Mayb this is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need a middleware to hook up the collection object to your requests:

```
var db    = mongo.db('localhost:27017/todo?auto_reconnect=true');
var tasks = db.collection('tasks');
...
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.db = { tasks : tasks }; // this exposes the collection as `req.db.tasks`
                              // to your route handlers
  next();
});
app.use(app.router);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In your routes/task.js, req is Express.js's request object.  It doesn't have "db" handle, that's why you are getting error:

```
500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'tasks' of undefined
```

In app.js, this is the incorrect way of getting the db handle:

```
var mongo = require("mongoskin");
var db = mongo.db('localhost:27017/todo?auto_reconnect=true', { safe:true })
   .collection('tasks')
   .find()
   .toArray(function(error, items){
       console.log(items);
   });
```

db code should be moved into a separate module (dbConnection.js for instance) so that every time you need the db handle, you just need to do this:

```
var db = require('./dbConnection').getDb();
```

routes/task.js needs to get the db handle to make database call.  So here are your revised app.js, routes/task.js and new dbConnection.js files:

dbConnection.js:

```
var open = function() {
    return require('mongoskin').db('localhost:27017/todo?auto_reconnect=true',
        {safe: true, strict: false}
    );
};

var db = open();

var dbConnection = {
    getDb: function() {
        if (!db) {
           db = open();
        }
        return db;
    }
};

module.exports = dbConnection;
```

routes/task.js:

```
var db = require('../dbConnection').getDb();

exports.list = function(req, res, next){
    var tasksCollection = db.collection('tasks');

    tasksCollection.find({ completed: false }).toArray(function(error, tasks){
        res.render('tasks', {
            title: "ToDo list",
            name: (tasks || [])
        });
    });
};
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var tasks = require('./routes/tasks');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/tasks', tasks.list);
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Now there is another error: Error: Failed to lookup view "tasks"

I have no ideas where i can find the error.

Comment: Beside moving the database code out, I left everything as the way they are and assuming that you have all the views.  If you don't, you can comment out app.set('views',...) and app.set('view engine',...), then instead of calling res.render(...), just call res.send({title: 'ToDo List', name: (tasks || [])})